# Multiple case Expressions in order by clause SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure given below in which I have to sort the results dynamically but it gives syntax error. please tell me the correct way to do it

```
SELECT *
FROM [TableName]
ORDER BY CASE @OrderBy
        WHEN 'DESC'
            THEN CASE @Sort
                    WHEN 'CreatedOn'
                        THEN CreatedOn
                    WHEN 'EmployeeName'
                        THEN EmployeeName
                    WHEN 'EmployeeCode'
                        THEN EmployeeCode
                    WHEN 'Country'
                        THEN Country
                    WHEN 'Location'
                        THEN Location
                    WHEN 'Skill'
                        THEN Skill
                    WHEN 'ProcessName'
                        THEN ProcessName
                    WHEN 'RoleName'
                        THEN RoleName
                    WHEN 'JoiningDate'
                        THEN JoiningDate
                    ELSE CreatedOn
                    END DESC
        ELSE CASE @Sort
                WHEN 'CreatedOn'
                    THEN CreatedOn
                WHEN 'EmployeeName'
                    THEN EmployeeName
                WHEN 'EmployeeCode'
                    THEN EmployeeCode
                WHEN 'Country'
                    THEN Country
                WHEN 'Location'
                    THEN Location
                WHEN 'Skill'
                    THEN Skill
                WHEN 'ProcessName'
                    THEN ProcessName
                WHEN 'RoleName'
                    THEN RoleName
                WHEN 'JoiningDate'
                    THEN JoiningDate
                ELSE CreatedOn
                END ASC
        END
```

Comment: Case expressions, not case statements...

Comment: @jarlh correct. Corrected the Question

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the syntax error you're getting when trying to execute the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax error is the use of `DESC` inside a `CASE` expression.  It is used to qualify the sort order; it is not understood inside a `CASE`.

In addition, you have potential run time errors.  The `case` expression returns a single value with a single type.  So, it is better to list each condition separately:

```
ORDER BY (CASE @OrderBy = 'DESC' AND @Sort = 'CreatedOn' THEN CreatedOn END) DESC,
         (CASE @OrderBy = 'DESC' AND @Sort = 'EmployeeName' THEN EmployeeName END) DESC,
         . . .
         (CASE @OrderBy = 'ASC' AND @Sort = 'CreatedOn' THEN CreatedOn END),
         (CASE @OrderBy = 'ASC' AND @Sort = 'EmployeeName' THEN EmployeeName END),
         . . .
```

To be honest, for this type of query, dynamic SQL is more efficient if you have indexes on the `ORDER BY` columns.